# refactor code to avoid DRY failed

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js

This code worked, but I feel redundant for the function body part, so I went ahead to refactor it.

```
const loginCommands = {
  loginAdmin: function(email, password) {
    return this.waitForElementVisible('body', 1000)
      .setValue('@email', email)
      .setValue('@password', password)
      .click('@submit')
      .waitForElementVisible('@adminMainMenu', 1000)
      .verify.attributeEquals('@adminMainMenu', 'data-role', 'admin')
  },

  loginMember: function(email, password) {
    return this.waitForElementVisible('body', 1000)
      .setValue('@email', email)
      .setValue('@password', password)
      .click('@submit')
      .waitForElementVisible('@adminMainMenu', 1000)
      .verify.attributeEquals('@adminMainMenu', 'data-role', 'member')
  }
}
```

I refactor above into this

```
const loginCommands = {

  function actions(this) {
    return this.setValue('@email', email)
    .setValue('@password', password)
    .click('@submit')
    .waitForElementVisible('@adminMainMenu', 1000)
  }

  loginAdmin: function(email, password) {
    return actions(this)
      .verify.attributeEquals('@adminMainMenu', 'data-role', 'admin')
  },

  loginMember: function(email, password) {
    return actions(this)
      .verify.attributeEquals('@adminMainMenu', 'data-role', 'member')
  }
}
```

but this doesn't run? The error I got is irrelevant, because I'm using nightwatch, it throw no error, but it simply skip the test. Can you spot any error in my refactoring?

Comment: Don't use `this` as an argument - use a different variable name instead.

Comment: @CertainPerformance tried, no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot declare a function inside a plain object like that. Assign the function to a property instead, and make sure to use a comma afterwards:

```
const loginCommands = {
  actions: function(email, password) {
    return this.setValue('@email', email)
      .setValue('@password', password)
      .click('@submit')
      .waitForElementVisible('@adminMainMenu', 1000)
  },
  loginAdmin: function(email, password) {
    return this.actions(email, password)
      .verify.attributeEquals('@adminMainMenu', 'data-role', 'admin')
  },
  loginMember: function(email, password) {
    return this.actions(email, password)
      .verify.attributeEquals('@adminMainMenu', 'data-role', 'member')
  }
}
```

Comment: Why you use arrow function for actions? I got this `ReferenceError: actions is not defined`

Comment: Arrow functions are fine to use whenever a full `function` isn't needed. See edit - just change to `this.actions(this)`. (or use your previous method plus a full function, except without `this` being an argument - just use the native `this` referencing the calling context)

Comment: also you have to pass email and password to action as argument, I think I got it, can you edit your code so that I can mark it as answer, thanks so much!

Comment: @MadelineRies Don’t forget to also upvote answers that you find helpful, especially the accepted one. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

> The error I got is irrelevant, because ...

Actually the error is relevant. It points you directly to the problem. The error is,

```
const loginCommands = {

  function actions(this) { // Error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

That's because `loginCommands` is supposed to be an object, and one of the ways to fix the syntax would be to create `action` as a property on that object:

```
const loginCommands = {
  actions: function(this) { 
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

But you should still avoid passing `this` around as a parameter in the function. If I had to refactor the original code, I would write it as follows:

```
const loginCommands = (function() {

    function actions(that) {
        return that.setValue('@email', email)
        .setValue('@password', password)
        .click('@submit')
        .waitForElementVisible('@adminMainMenu', 1000)
    }

    return {
        loginAdmin: function(email, password) {
            return actions(this)
              .verify.attributeEquals('@adminMainMenu', 'data-role', 'admin')
        },

        loginMember: function(email, password) {
            return actions(this)
              .verify.attributeEquals('@adminMainMenu', 'data-role', 'member')
        }
    };
}());
```

This would keep the action function in a closure, and hence it cannot be invoked through `loginCommands.actions()`.

I have also changed `this` to `that` when it is used inside `actions` function, as it should reduce some confusion around it.

Comment: thanks for the explaination but eventually I put the actions function as object and access it like this.actions